# View sqlite DB created in samsung s duos 7562

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I have created sqlite DB programatically in samsung s duos 7562.
Is there any way to view and explore db so that I can ensure that DB have the value that I have expected??

I have rooted my phone and have tries many Db explorer apps. But i was not able to find the DB file.

Comment: where did you look for it and how did you try to access the sqlite file? the location is well documented and if you have rooted your phone you should be able to retrieve it.

Comment: I have checked in /mnt/sdcard/Android/datafiles..    But i cant find my app's package structure.

Answer (score 0):

usually, it is in `/data/data/your.app.packagename/database/`

to access it using file manager app, your phone needs to be rooted.

you can try accessing it in desktop via `adb pull` command. example: `adb pull /data/data/your.app.packagename/database/what.db /home/user/`

Comment: i need to see my changes in the tables all the time how can i do it ?